# webhook for youtube comments

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

first of all im using youtube api to create my app. im in progress to creating an app to get every comment from my youtube channel and reply to it. it's mainly used for customer relationship activity.  right now im using a script which call youtube api to pull its data (all comments from my channel) every 30 seconds. but it takes a lot of time and burdens my server. its not quota friendly too.

so here are my questions

is there no webhook or something on youtube so i can get a notification / event every time there's comment on my channel and reply to it. something similar to facebook webhook.